# How can i convert an integer into a ZZ number using NTL lib?

Tags: c++, ntl

Here's the question. I need to convert some integer variables to ZZ class or vice verse. How could i do that? I've tried using (ZZ) before the integer or (int) before the ZZ class but all failed.

Comment: Any chance you can post the code you are using and what the exact error message is?

Comment: How about the ZZ before the variable name? That's the normal way to do things. See here for example http://www.shoup.net/ntl/doc/tour-ex1.html

Answer (score 2):

You haven't posted any code, but I'm sure your question can be answered [here](http://www.shoup.net/ntl/doc/tour-ex1.html), pasted verbatim for your entertainment:

One can also assign a value of type long to a ZZ:

```
ZZ x;
x = 1;
```

Note that one cannot write

```
ZZ x = 1;  // error
```

to initialize a ZZ. Instead, one could write

```
ZZ x = conv<ZZ>(1);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helps! But what if I want to convert the integer in ZZ back to 'long' type? Here is part of my code.                                                                                       i have            mat_ZZ a;( 1 * n)
           vec_ZZ b; ( 1 element only)                                           what i want to do is to get all the integers in a and b out and then get their reciprocals and finally sort the reciprocals. i don't know how to do using ZZ class. so i want to convert the integers back to 'long' type.  How could i achieve this???  thanks very mush!

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to answer but it might help someone out there. As it was asked in the question

> I need to convert some integer variables to ZZ class or vice verse

and also in the comments

> what if I want to convert the integer in ZZ back to 'long' type?

Here is the answer, in NTL library the conversion has been provided in tools namespace. Following example demonstrates how to convert from ZZ back to long and vice verse:

```
ZZ z1 = ZZ(2);
ZZ z2;
long a = 0;
conv(a, z1); //converts zz type to long

conv(z2,a); //converts long to zz type

cout << a; //prints 2

cout << zz2; //prints 2
```